# WakeLock released yet the app keeps the CPU "awake"

Tags: android, power-management, wakelock, android-wake-lock

I have a service that reads sensor data in the background for which I need to keep the CPU awake for a while until I read the data.

In the `onCreate` method of the service, I create a new `WakeLock` as follow:

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakeLock = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
```

In the `onStartCommand` method, I acquire the lock as follows:

```
if(!mWakeLock.isHeld())
    mWakeLock.acquire();
```

And in the `onDestory` method I release it by:

```
if(mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
    mWakeLock.release();
    Log.i("", "Wakelock released");
}
```

When the service is destroyed, I get the log message as I have provided in `onDestroy` "Wakelock released". However, the CPU is kept awake for hours by the app. This is the information from the battery stats that I've got. You can see that the CPU is kept awake for more than 7 hours draining the battery like crazy!

[image]

Could anyone please tell me what the problem is and how I can prevent the app from NOT making the CPU to sleep even after the lock is released?

Comment: You can check with `adb shell dumpsys power` if your application still has the `WakeLock` and to make sure that the `WakeLock` is released correctly.

Comment: Hmm it does show that my app is holding a lock. Well, I'll check and go through my code again. Thanks!

Comment: Search for "Wakelock released" ;)

Comment: Looking at commonsware [implementation](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/blob/master/wakeful/src/com/commonsware/cwac/wakeful/WakefulIntentService.java) he places the unlock in a finally in onHandle intent - maybe onDestroy does not always run ? You check for `!mWakeLock.isHeld()` which seems preventing the lock being reaquired but what if it is a different lock ? Dunno if onDestroy is called on Service instance destroy - never quite got what happens to an instance of Service class. Trying a static lock ?